# Index Error: List Appending Syntax Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm having problems with this block of code:

```
while numSelector <= len(nums)+1:
    average = average + nums[numSelector]
    numSelector += 1
```

and I'm getting this error from the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\nghia_000\Documents\Programming\Python27\AveragingCalculator.py", line 11, in 
>       average = average + nums[numSelector]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If the length of a list is n, then it contains elements at indices 0 to n-1. Try:

```
numSelector = 0
while numSelector < len(nums):
    average = average + nums[numSelector]
    numSelector += 1
```

A better way would be to directly iterate over the numbers present in the list using a for loop:

```
for num in nums:
    average += num
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `len(nums) == 5`. Then the line:

`while numSelector <= len(nums) + 1:`

means "keep going until `numSelector` is no more than 6. But `numSelector` only has five elements in it -- 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the condition to **numSelector <= len(nums)-1** or **numSelector < len(nums)** will do for you.